Handling Pagination in Python
I'm working on a FastAPI application that needs to interact with GitHub's API and save the retrieved data in MongoDB. Specifically, I need to:
Fetch all users from GitHub's API using pagination.
For each user, fetch all their repositories using pagination.
Store the fetched users and their repositories in MongoDB.
I am using the httpx library for making HTTP requests.
async def fetch_users_from_github(per_page=10):
    page = 1
    users = []
    while True:
        url = f"{GITHUB_API_URL}/users?per_page={per_page}&page={page}"
        headers = {"Authorization": f"token {GITHUB_TOKEN}"}
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()
            if not data:
                break
            users.extend(data)
            page += 1
    return users

async def fetch_repos_from_github(username, per_page=10):
    page = 1
    repos = []
    while True:
        url = f"{GITHUB_API_URL}/users/{username}/repos?per_page={per_page}&page={page}"
        headers = {"Authorization": f"token {GITHUB_TOKEN}"}
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()
            if not data:
                break
            repos.extend(data)
            page += 1
    return repos


async def fetch_and_store_users_and_repos():
    users = await fetch_users_from_github()
    for user in users:
        save_user(user)
        repos = await fetch_repos_from_github(user["login"])
        save_repos(repos)



What is the problem you are facing ?

what is best practice to pagination? i know i can know How many pages are there? how can do the code better?

I think your solution cool, maybe better improve it with python generator yield data to make parsing uniform.

what about to get the page from api  i see some of them do that
